# stop matching string in regex after my pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match a string pattern and my regex is

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*(-|\s)*Iphone 7(\s|-)?(\p{N}GB)?\B/i
```

And the string with which I am trying to match is `Apple Iphone 7 Plus 16 Gb`. I want to match the exact regex i.e. Iphone 7 should only match with following

- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 16 gb
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 32GB - Silver
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 plus (should not match)
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7s (should not match)

Please let me know what I am doing wrong?
Here is regex [link](https://regex101.com/r/cX82xh/1)

Comment: Why are you using `[a-zA-Z0-9]*(-|\s)*` instead of `apple iphone` as you say "it should only match with following"?

Comment: Everything up to Apple Iphone  7 works, so its only the last part that isn't workign

Comment: @SaggingRufus yes, that is the issue.

Comment: apple iphone 7 plus (should not match).....should not match or this is not matching.....clear this confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to well unsderstand your need, but how about:

```
/^.*?iphone 7(?:\s+(?:plus\s+)?\d+\s?gb.*)?$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
/               : regex delimiter
  ^             : begining of string
    .*?         : 0 or more any characters not greedy
    iphone 7    : literally
    (?:         : start non capture group
      \s+       : 1 or more spaces
      (?:       : start non capture group
        plus    : literally
        \s+     : 1 or more spaces
      )?        : end group^, optional
      \d+       : 1 or more digits
      \s?       : 1 optional space
      gb        : literally
      .*        : 0 or more any character
    )?          : end group, optional
  $             : end of string
/i              : regex delimiter, case insensitive
```

**In action:**

```
$tests = array(
'any digits or string apple iphone 7',
'any digits or string apple iphone 7 16 gb',
'any digits or string apple iphone 7 32GB - Silver',
'any digits or string apple iphone 7 plus',
'any digits or string apple iphone 7s',
);
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "$test\t ==> ";
    if (preg_match('/^.*?iphone 7(?:\s+(?:plus\s+)?\d+\s?gb.*)?$/i', $test)) {
        echo "match\n";
    } else {
        echo "doesn't match\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
any digits or string apple iphone 7  ==> match
any digits or string apple iphone 7 16 gb    ==> match
any digits or string apple iphone 7 32GB - Silver    ==> match
any digits or string apple iphone 7 plus     ==> doesn't match
any digits or string apple iphone 7s     ==> doesn't match
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation but the plus is just a placeholder, there can be iphone 6s which should not match with iphone 6 but iphone 6 should match with iphone 16gb and so

Answer (score 0):

If you are really only interested in the `Apple Iphone 7` bit of the string, and you're using PHP, why not simply do:

```
if (stripos($string,'Apple Iphone 7 Plus') !== FALSE) echo 'Wow a 7 Plus!';
else if (stripos($string,'Apple Iphone 7') !== FALSE) echo 'It is only a 7';
```

In other words: Avoid using complex regular expressions when you can, and only use them when they are needed.

Comment: I have to follow a pattern as I described in the question so I cant simply use `strpos`

Comment: it will also match iphone 7 plus.

Comment: Yes, true, but simply adding in an extra line will solve that.

Comment: You can make a case for using reg exp when parsing user agent strings. My only point is that reg exp should only be used when other options fail. You find them difficult, other people as well. They can make your code unreadable, and unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

With this regex you can match and also if you want can extract some info about it

```
(?!apple iphone .* plus)(?:apple iphone 7)(?>\s(?<storage>\d+)?\s?(?:gb))?
```

You can see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9kh1rn/9)

I have updated a bit, now will match with the following

- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 16 gb
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 32GB
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 [any digits or string]
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 16 gb [any digits or string]
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 32GB [any digits or string]

Will not match with the following

- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 plus
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 plus [any digits or string]
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 16 gb plus
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 16 gb plus [any digits or string]
- [any digits or string] apple iphone 7 32GB plus [any digits or string]

Comment: This is matching `apple iphone 7gBBBBB GGG`

Comment: @Toto try the new version

Comment: That's better, but it matches `apple iphone 77777GG`. There is also a typo in the character class, you have 2 `b`

Comment: @Toto I think now it's more robust